# C++ Expecting Primary Expression before '.' token

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me why the following gives me an error, and how to fix.

The compile error is:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

Simplified class and Method:

```
class test{
    private:
        int data;
    public:
        test() : data(1){}
        test(const test& copy):data(copy.data){} //copy constructor
        int getData(){
            return data;
        }
};
```

This method wont compile like this:

```
int getDataFromClass(const test& src){
    return test.getData();
}
```

But it does like this

```
int getDataFromClass(const test& src){
    test t = test(src);
    return t.getData();
}
```

The second method defeats the purpose of passing in the data by reference and so is undesirable.

I want to be able to pass a class in by reference, as a const, and be able to use some getter methods without having to create a local copy.

Comment: `test` is a type. You need an object of that type.

Comment: `return src.getData();` Also, declare `getData` as const.

Answer (score 5):

Your variable is `const` and you are calling a non-const member function.

Redefine your member function as `int getData() const {` and you should be fine.

And as Ivaylo Strandjev said, use `src` to access the object.

Comment: Your first phrase does not answer the specific error message and your second phrase does not solve the problem, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
int getDataFromClass(const test& src){
    return test.getData();
}
```

Here you should use `src` as it it the variable name. `test` is the class name and the compiler complains that you try to invoke a method on it.

Answer (score 2):

Because in

```
int getDataFromClass(const test& src){
    return test.getData();
}
```

`test` is a type, not an object.